# Show/Hide Checkout Fields according to answer to previous question

Tags: wordpress, forms, validation, woocommerce, checkout

I use a multi-step checkout plugin.

I ask customers if they have allergies, using checkboxes.
The first checkbox is *none* followed by *chicken, beef* etc.

I wish to remove the *none* checkbox option and ask that question before this.
e.g.
I wish to ask "do you have dietary requirements?" and handle the *yes* or *no* as a radio button.

I wish to hide the checkbox allergies options by default, and only show this question if the customer selects *yes* in the question above.
I would appreciate advice.

Is it advised or bad to use something like this?

```
$('.dietary_restrictions').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('.additional_allergies').show();
    } else {
        $('.additional_allergies').hide();
    }
})
```

Additionally, my checkout plugin does support conditional questions but the options for showing and hiding questions is a drop-down which allows me to show and hide based only on the customer or product, not based on questions or answers.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your jQuery example for showing additional options looks fine. These aren't a security risk in any way so I think you're fine going this way. Maybe the check-out plugin has filter/action hooks to create custom options? Can you provide the plugin name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it worked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#dietary_restrictions').click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#additional_allergies_field').show();
    } else {
        $('#additional_allergies_field').hide();
    }
})
</script>
```

and I had to set css to hide the ID by default.

Answer (score 1):

its jquery and you need to place inside  and use jQuery instead of $

```
<script>
function dietary_restrictions() {
    jQuery('input#dietary_restrictions').click(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
            jQuery('input#additional_allergies_field').show();
        } else {
            jQuery('input#additional_allergies_field').hide();
        }
}
</script>
```

or just paste it in your .js file inside a jQuery(document).ready({});

Comment: I can't say why but this didn't work. Thanks though.